# Does choice of programming language affect protection against DoS, specifically Ping Flood?

Tags: web, ping, ddos, denial-of-service

I am building a REST website and have to pick programming tools based on their protection against DoS, specifically Ping Flood.

I have searched multiple blogs and read research papaers on IEEE; however, none of them mention how choice of programming language affects DoS protection.

Is there any difference between  Java Spring Boot, Ruby on Rails, MEAN stack or other framework I haven't mentioned from the perspective of defence agaisnt Ping Flood?

I would like to leave Firewall aside, for research purposes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Usually, you will try to protect the app on the network layer, not on the app itself. You want to drop bad packages as soon as possible.

Cloudflare, the CDN and network security company, wrote about dropping packages ([they are dropping 10 million packages per second!](https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-drop-10-million-packets/)) and none of these packages are handled by the application, but in the network layer